# How to access control in control template of a marker symbol

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

I am trying to add a custom control to esri map. For that I am using Marker symbol, now I have to access 'eventsRadial1' control from code behind which is in the controltemplate of a markersymbol. How can I do that?

```
<esri:MarkerSymbol x:Key="EventsRadialSymbol">
                <esri:MarkerSymbol.ControlTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <my:EventsRadial HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,15,0,0"                 
                        x:Name="eventsRadial1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>                   
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </esri:MarkerSymbol.ControlTemplate>
</esri:MarkerSymbol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have solved that problem, but i have struggled with the same issue and came up with a solution.

First create a custom marker symbol of your own like below code:

```
public class TextBoxMarkerSymbol : MarkerSymbol
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxMarkerSymbol), new PropertyMetadata(OnTextChanged));
    //private string contentText;
    public string ContentText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ContentTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentTextProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    public TextBoxMarkerSymbol(int width, int height)
    {

        string template = "<ControlTemplate " +
                            "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>" +
                            "<Canvas>";
        template += "<TextBox Name='txtText' Text='{Binding Symbol.ContentText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}'  Height='" + height + "' Width='" + width + "' />";
        template += " </Canvas>" +
        "</ControlTemplate>";

        System.IO.MemoryStream templateStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(template));
        this.ControlTemplate = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(templateStream) as ControlTemplate;

    }
}
```

the trick is here you can't reach your control directly because marker controls are not visual.

So you have to define dependency properties for your controls properties, so you can bind them by using Symbol.

then you can use your symbol as below code:

```
                TextBoxMarkerSymbol mSymbol = new TextBoxMarkerSymbol(width, height);
                mSymbol.OffsetX = width / 2;
                mSymbol.OffsetY = height / 2;
                mSymbol.ContentText = "test binding";
```

have a nice day.